# Optimisation of division in gcc

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc

Here's some code (full program follows later in the question):

```
template <typename T>
T fizzbuzz(T n) {
    T count(0);
    #if CONST
        const T div(3);
    #else
        T div(3);
    #endif
    for (T i(0); i <= n; ++i) {
        if (i % div == T(0)) count += i;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now, if I call this template function with `int`, then I get a factor of 6 performance difference according to whether I define CONST or not:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)

$ make -B wrappedint CPPFLAGS="-O3 -Wall -Werror -DWRAP=0 -DCONST=0" &&
 time ./wrappedint
g++  -O3 -Wall -Werror -DWRAP=0 -DCONST=0   wrappedint.cpp   -o wrappedi
nt
484573652

real    0m2.543s
user    0m2.059s
sys     0m0.046s

$ make -B wrappedint CPPFLAGS="-O3 -Wall -Werror -DWRAP=0 -DCONST=1" &&
 time ./wrappedint
g++  -O3 -Wall -Werror -DWRAP=0 -DCONST=1   wrappedint.cpp   -o wrappedi
nt
484573652

real    0m0.655s
user    0m0.327s
sys     0m0.046s
```

Examining the disassembly shows that in the fast (const) case, the modulo has been turned into a multiplication and shift type thing, whereas in the slow (non-const) case it's using `idivl`.

Even worse, if I try to wrap my integer in a class, then the optimisation doesn't happen whether I use const or not. The code always uses `idivl` and runs slow:

```
#include <iostream>

struct WrappedInt {
    int v;
    explicit WrappedInt(const int &val) : v(val) {}
    bool operator<=(const WrappedInt &rhs) const { return v <= rhs.v; }
    bool operator==(const WrappedInt &rhs) const { return v == rhs.v; }
    WrappedInt &operator++() { ++v; return *this; }
    WrappedInt &operator+=(const WrappedInt &rhs) { v += rhs.v; return *this; }
    WrappedInt operator%(const WrappedInt &rhs) const 
        { return WrappedInt(v%rhs.v); }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &s, WrappedInt w) {
    return s << w.v;
}

template <typename T>
T fizzbuzz(T n) {
    T count(0);
    #if CONST
        const T div(3);
    #else
        T div(3);
    #endif
    for (T i(0); i <= n; ++i) {
        if (i % div == T(0)) count += i;
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    #if WRAP
        WrappedInt w(123456789);
        std::cout << fizzbuzz(w) << "\n";
    #else
        std::cout << fizzbuzz<int>(123456789) << "\n";
    #endif
}
```

My questions are:

1) Is there a simple principle of C++ itself, or gcc's optimisation, which explains why this happens, or is it just a case of "various heuristics run, this is the code you get"?

2) Is there any way to make the compiler realise that my locally-declared and never-referenced const WrappedInt can be treated as a compile-time const value? I want this thing to be a straight replacement for int in templates.

3) Is there a known way of wrapping an int such that the compiler can discard the wrapping when optimising? The goal is that WrappedInt will be a policy-based template. But if a "do-nothing" policy results in essentially arbitrary 6x speed penalties over int, I'm better off special-casing that situation and using int directly.

Comment: In case it causes any confusion - I probably should have renamed my function "fizz" when I removed the "|| i % 5" ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing its just the severely old GCC version you are running. The oldest compiler I have on my machine - gcc-4.1.2, performs the fast way with both the non-const and the wrap versions (and does so at only -O1).

Comment: Any particular reason you haven't upgraded in 4 years?

Comment: Cygwin defaults to 3.4. I assume they're still using it to build cygwin itself, or something. It has a gcc-4 package, though, so I'll try that. Not as bad as the 12 months+ that cygwin's version of gnupg contained a critical security flaw fixed upstream.

Answer (score 1):

Try combining `const int v` in your WrappedInt class with `const T` in your fizzbuzz function and see if the compiler can optimize that.

By declaring `const int` you've created a special case - a compile time constant. The compiler knows what the value is, and can optimize it more heavily than a value that could possibly change during the run of the program.

Comment: Unfortunately `WrappedInt` has two operators which modify `v`. But introducing a new class, `WrappedConstInt` with them removed, adding a suitable `operator%`, and making `div` a `const WrappedConstInt`, does not trigger the optimisation. It runs slow.

Comment: And I understand that "const int" is special. However, even when non-const, the compiler is pulling the value into a register, and the register is never modified in the loop. So I was rather hoping (a) that some DFA would allow it to see that a local int which is never modified and no references taken, is as good as const, and give it the treatment, and/or (b) that a const struct containing an int is just as const as a `const int`.

Comment: So I guess the question becomes, "is there a strong reason why neither (a) nor (b) happens, or is it just that gcc doesn't manage it?"

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a known way of wrapping an int such that the compiler can discard the wrapping when optimising?

Try passing `WrappedInt` by value. Then `WrappedInt`s can be passed in registers. Pass-by-const-reference sometimes forces gcc to fall back to the stack for argument passing.

About the `int` vs `const int` slowdown, I can only speculate that GCC is trying to play it safe in the face of aliasing. Basically, if it cannot prove that `div` is not an alias for another, more accessible variable, it cannot turn it into a constant. If you declare it const, GCC assumes it's not aliased and performs the conversion into a constant. Apart from the `idivl`, you should also see a memory fetch, once, when entering the function, as opposed to immediate values being used for the `const` case.

Comment: In both the wrapped and non-const int cases, div is initialised with "`movl $3, %edi`" and never touches memory. And changing all the operators of WrappedInt (as well as the constructor) to pass by value doesn't enable the optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in speed is caused by the compiler not knowing if "div" will change value. When it is non-const, it is treating it like a variable being passed in. It could be anything, and so the compiler will use an instruction that divides two variables - idivl. When you say that it's const, the compiler is free to treat it exactly as if you'd typed:

```
if (i  % 3 == 0)
```

I'm kind of surprised that it didn't use bitwise AND(&).

The WrappedInt isn't being optimized because, well, its not an int. Its a class.

Something that you could do is incorporate fizzbuzz into WrappedInt.

Comment: Only the modulo of powers of two can be expressed using AND.