# Can const-correctness improve performance?

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-optimization, const-correctness

I have read numerous times that enforcing const-correctness in your C or C++ code is not only a good practice with regards to maintainability, but also it may allow your compiler to perform optimizations. However, I have read the complete opposite, too — that it does not affect performance at all.

Therefore, do you have examples where const correctness may aid your compiler with improving your program's performance?

Comment: Const-correctness is one of the BEST practices as regards to maintainability. If your C++ code is not const-correct, it is basically a pile of crap, waiting for disaster to strike. It is not intended to affect performance.

Comment: Here's an example where `const` made a performance difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121791/optimisation-of-division-in-gcc. It was essentially a quality-of-implementation issue, though. `const` didn't determine whether the compiler *could* legally make the optimisation, it just happened that version of the compiler failed to make it when it was missing.

Comment: I'm quite sure "morgennebel" missed a 'only' in the first sentence: It makes much more sense with "is not only a good practice".

Comment: Martin, I think you're missing an 'only' after 'not' as in 'not only a good practice'

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`const` correctness can't improve performance because `const_cast` and `mutable` are in the language, and allow code to conformingly break the rules. This gets even worse in C++11, where your `const` data may e.g. be a pointer to a `std::atomic`, meaning the compiler has to respect changes made by other threads.

That said, it is trivial for the compiler to look at the code it generates and determine if it actually writes to a given variable, and apply optimizations accordingly.

That all said, `const` correctness is a *good* thing with respect to maintainability. Otherwise, clients of your class could break that class's internal members. For instance, consider the standard `std::string::c_str()` -- if it couldn't return a const value, you'd be able to screw around with the internal buffer of the string!

Don't use `const` for performance reasons. Use it for maintainability reasons.

Comment: "you'd be able to screw around with the internal buffer of the string!" - crucially, you'd be able to *accidentally* screw around with the internal buffer. Compiler errors due to `const` are signposts, saying, "you're doing something stupid".

Comment: ... and const-casts are signposts saying, "the author of this code is trying to do something clever" ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop - or const-cast are signposts saying "I'm trying to bolt up a const-correct bunch of code to a non-const-correct one, and I can't fix either one". Which, let me tell you, is in no way clever, just annoying.

Comment: @Michael - yes, fair point. Perhaps the original signpost isn't "you're doing something stupid", rather "someone's doing something stupid".

Comment: Godbolt and Arduino told me that const correctness is not just for fun.

Comment: @dgrat: Do you have an example?

Comment: @BillyONeal
Well one part was already answered below and it is clear which version should be slightly faster. For Arduino, the compiler tends to move variables with a const more likely into the flash memory instead of the RAM. Which is desirable as for smaller micro controllers RAM is limited.

Comment: @dgrat: Marking *data* as being "born const" is different than observing const-correctness in a codebase.

Comment: Comparing the above answer and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/357607/3736444 - I'm also confused. I understood that with `const_cast` you can't simply "remove" `const` and work with an object as it wasn't `const`. So `const` seems to me a good indicator for optimizations... Could anybody clarify?

Answer (score 45):

Yes it can.

Most `const`s are purely for the benefit of the programmer and do not help the compiler optimize because it's legal to cast them away and so they don't tell the compiler anything useful for optimization. However, some `const`s cannot be (legally) cast away and these do provide the compiler with useful information for optimization.

As an example, access to a global variable defined with a `const` type can be inlined while one without a `const` type cannot be inlined because it might change at runtime.

https://godbolt.org/g/UEX4NB

C++:

```
int foo1 = 1;
const int foo2 = 2;

int get_foo1() {
    return foo1;
}

int get_foo2() {
    return foo2;
}
```

asm:

```
foo1:
        .long   1
foo2:
        .long   2
get_foo1():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR foo1[rip] ; foo1 must be accessed by address
        pop     rbp
        ret
get_foo2():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 2 ; foo2 has been replaced with an immediate 2
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

In practical terms, keep in mind that while `const` can improve performance, in most cases it won't or it will but the change will not be noticeable. The primary usefulness of `const` is not optimization.

---

Steve Jessop gives another example in his comment on the original question which brings up something worth mentioning. In a block scope, it's possible for a compiler to deduce if a variable will be mutated and optimize accordingly, regardless of `const`, because the compiler can see all uses of the variable. In contrast, in the example above, it's impossible to predict if `foo1` will be mutated since it could be modified in other translation units. I suppose a hypothetical sentient ultra-compiler could analyze an entire program and determine if it's valid to inline access to `foo1`... but real compilers can't.

Comment: @ericcurtin That's why I didn't mention the compiler in the answer. Normally, when posting generated assembly, I'd make sure to state the compiler and version, but this is an optimization that every major optimizing compiler will perform so I didn't want to give the impression that this was particular to one compiler.

Comment: @Acorn Here's the same example but with a class object: https://godbolt.org/z/R-Zfgc. Also, the variables in the example have external linkage.

Answer (score 8):

A bit old, but still applies: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm
And some more: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Answer (score 6):

in my experience, no

For scalar variables, compiler is able to determine whenever the value is changed and perform necessary optimization itself.

For array pointers, const correctness is no guarantee that values are really constant in presence of potential aliasing problems.  Hence compiler can not use const modifier alone to perform optimizations

if you are looking optimization, you should consider [`__restrict__`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/topic/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc03restrict_type_qualifier.htm) or special function modifiers/attributes: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: link in answer is is dead but here is info on __restrict__ keyword https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c