# Const as Much as Possible in C++

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I have been working on some legacy C++ code and my objective is to optimize the code as much as possible. I was reading somewhere and found this code

```
// Bad Idea
class MyClass
{
public:
  void do_something(int i);
  void do_something(std::string str);
};


// Good Idea
class MyClass
{
public:
  void do_something(const int i);
  void do_something(const std::string &str);
};
```

This code says that use `const` as much as possible. Could someone explain if this has a significant performance improvement or if it is related to something else?

Comment: ***if this has a significant performance improvement?*** That will depend on the code.

Comment: Step 1: Check the assembly. Step 2: Measure it.

Comment: Code for correctness first.  Are you going to modify `i` or `str`?  If so making them const is not what you want to do.

Comment: Microoptimizations are evil.

Comment: `const` generally does not affect performance.

Comment: This question has been asked before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435026/can-const-correctness-improve-performance The top post goes into fairly good detail about why constness doesn't improve performance but is still a good idea.

Comment: @Evgeny It's that kinda thinking that leads to word programs with 5-minute boot times.

Comment: Using a `const std::string &` instead of `std::string` may save a copy, though if `do_something` is a sink you may instead disable a move and force a copy later on.

Comment: @George, it better have 5-minute boot time than 5-minute crash time.

Comment: @Evgeny Optimisations/Micro Optimisations very rarely lead to crashes. It usually only happens when the code is already awful, or attempting to optimise out smart pointers from code that heavily relies on them (arguably code like that could fall under the "awful" category).