# How to display colour components of a picture in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing

I am trying to teach myself some basics of Signal Theory, more specifically Image Processing however I am trying to just get the hang of it from first principles (mostly). I have access to an Academic license for Matlab however I would like to learn the principles using C/C++ (as it is free to use) hence my IDE of choice is Qt.

My current project is to read in an image using `QImage` and then display the red, green and blue "image parts". However I am not sure how to do this using Qt. My idea is as follows; when displaying the red part set all Green and Blue values for all pixels to zero and display the output and then repeat for each colour component.

```
QImage my_original_image;
my_original_image.load(":/pic.png");

ui->img_label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(my_original_image));
```

The above code snippet is what I use to read in an image and display it onto a label and it works for me.

```
for (int row=0; row<my_original_image.width(); row++)
{
    for (int col=0; col<my_original_image.height(); col++)
    {
        int r = qRed(my_original_image.pixel(row,col));
        qDebug() << "red " << r <<endl;
        std::cout << r << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The above code snippet is what I have managed to put together from other forums and all it does is display the red value for all the pixels in the picture.

Herewith my question: How can I modify the above code in order to display the red, green and blue "image parts" into a label similar to the 1st code snippet?

Comment: "I would like to learn the principles using C/C++". First principle to learn: C and C++ are two different languages, they have similarities, and there can be code that can be compiled as C and as C++, but your code is not valid C (there is no `std::cout` in C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking is to separate the RGB components into individual images.

One way to do so (not very efficient, but that follows your previous code) is this one:

```
QImage red(img.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32); // a new image with the same size
for (int row = 0; row < img.height(); ++row) {
  for (int col = 0; col < img.width(); ++col) {
    const auto color = img.pixelColor(col, row);
    const auto c = color.red();
    red.setPixelColor(col, row, QColor(c, 0, 0, c > 0 ? color.alpha() : 0));
  }
}
ui->imgRed->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(red));
```

The adjust in alpha channel is just for visualization purposes, otherwise you'll have a black color in those pixels where the red component is 0; if that's what you're looking for, replace `c > 0 ? color.alpha() : 0` with just the alpha channel of original image `color.alpha()`.

You can repeat the same with the remaining green and blue components.

[image]

Adjust the image format and remove alpha channel if not present in your image.

PS: just as a note, you were swapping the meaning `col` and `row` variables, you should use rows when traversing from top to bottom (height), and columns when using the width.

Comment: Thank you! In between me asking the question and receiving your answer I managed to get a working algorithm however I had the exact problem that you foresaw, the black colour in non red pixels.

Comment: ```c > 0 ? color.alpha() : 0``` what is the purpose of this statement?

Comment: Also why did you use the ```const``` preceding the ```c ``` and ```color``` variables, what purpose does it serve in this context?

Comment: @BenjaminBeer that condition is to preserve the original alpha channel (assuming it exists) when the red component is non-zero, otherwise it set the color to be fully transparent

Comment: @BenjaminBeer the const keyboard is just a custom to set as constants everything that is not intended to be modified later

Comment: Thank you for your excellent response! Does the const improve the operation of the coding? (I apologise if it is a noob question however it is an entirely new concept to me).

Comment: @BenjaminBeer it is basically for correctness, you cannot ensure the compiler will optimize more your code when using const... take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3435076/1485885