# C++ const modifier with primitive types

Tags: c++

Should I pay attention on `const` modifier working with primitive types? Which one is more syntactically correct and why?

First version:

```
float Foo::bar(float a, float b)
{
    return (a + b) / 2.0f;
}
```

Second version:

```
const float Foo::bar(const float a, const float b)
{
    return (a + b) / 2.0f;
}
```

Third version:

```
float Foo::bar(const float a, const float b)
{
    return (a + b) / 2.0f;
}
```

I know the primitive-typed variables are copied when passing to some method, but what way is more clear?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would say that the third version is most "correct".

You tell the compiler that the arguments are `const`, which is correct since you don't modify them. This can help the compiler with optimizations for passing the arguments, as well as in the calculations.

And the return type is not `const` since the caller may want to modify the returned value. If the caller doesn't want to modify the returned value, then it's up to the caller to assign it to a `const` variable.

I would also have added `const` to the function declaration, since the function does not modify anything in the object:

```
float Foo::bar(const float a, const float b) const
```

Since the function doesn't access any members of the object, then I would make it `static` as well.

Comment: +1 const member function (though a helpful addition to what the OP asked).

Comment: "the caller may want to modify the returned value" -- although they'll need a `const_cast` (or C-style cast) to do so, since it's an rvalue expression of primitive type. So even if it's non-const they can't get a non-const reference to it without a cast. Not sure that's something we *really* need to support, but more importantly if your function returns a `const` object of class type that's generally bad, because it prevents moving from it or calling non-const member functions of it.

Comment: One further detail, if the return type were `bool` it's good to make it `const` to avoid accidental assignment in conditional expressions. This can be avoided by turning up compiler warnings, but, once bitten twice shy.

Comment: Making parameters (and scoped variables) `const` could also help to avoid creating bugs during maintenance.  Maybe not in this simple example, but in a complex function with many variables with similar names, it could help.

Answer (score 4):

First of, all the definitions you provide are syntactly correct. If they compile, then they are correct syntax-wise.

The `const` qualifier on parameters has only one purpose: prevent the function body from modifying the `const` qualified arguments.

In the specific case of your example code, the method `Foo::bar` does not modify the arguments, so using the `const` qualifier has no effect whatsoever.

However, you might want to use `const` by default in all cases, and only remove it for situations where you want to allow modifications. Hence, applying it to the parameters of `Foo::bar` is a good idea. I think it's good practice, though I shall admit that I seldom use it, because of the bit of noise it incurs, which may reduce readability.

Another thing to consider is that for primitive types, or more precisely types which are not pointers or do not contain pointers, modifying an argument passed by value (ie. not by reference) will not have any side effect: parameters of these types really act as initialized local variables (which can be handy, but may also be confusing). For pointers, any modification of the pointed data will leak to the outside world. That's another good reason to use the `const` qualifier both on the pointer and *on the pointed part of the type*.

All in all, using the `const` qualifier as much as possible will help make the code less error prone, and can also help the compiler optimize the resulting programme.

Using a reference for these types however shouldn't make any significant change, if these types describe values fitting in a CPU register (which is generally the case),

So, all three versions of the method should boil down to the same generated assembly code.

In the particular case of primitive return types, it does not matter. the return value can be converted back and forth to a `const` qualified one.

Others have also mentioned the interest of the `const` qualifier on the function itself. While out of the original question scope, I will also say that it is indeed better when possible (like for `Foo::bar`) to qualify a function as `const`.

Comment: "will also help the compiler optimize" -- *will* is a bit strong. I asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121791, a long time ago, and the answer turned out to be that const-qualifying a primitive variable helped gcc 3 to optimize, but gcc 4 was smart enough not to need help.

Comment: well, maybe. For primitive types perhaps it does not really matter that much.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference at all between the 2nd and the 3rd versions. Choose one which is the shortest to type :)

There's a little difference between the 1st and the 3rd. You might prefer the 3rd if you are afraid of accidentally modifying `a` and `b` inside the function.

Comment: There is a difference between the 2nd and 3rd answers though. The 2nd returns a 'const float' which means the value it returns cannot be changed. in the 3rd one you can, of course.

Comment: The return is primitive not an lvalue, so the const on the return doesn't do anything.  For example, it's illegal to write `Foo::bar(1, 2)++` in any of the three signatures in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It does not matter.

Long answer: Since you are passing the two arguments by value and returning the argument by value. Either one of those are fine, but you will more commonly see the first version.

If you pass by reference (as others have suggested), then it does matter, and you should use a const-reference. However, passing primitive types by reference doesn't really give you any advantages or make sense (if it's a const reference). The reason for this is because passing by primitive types by value will not produce any overhead compared to passing primitive by reference.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to say that with primitives it may well be more efficient to actually copy them. When you pass a reference, the compiler still has to pass bytes on the stack, and then has to dereference the address to get the content.

In addition, passing by value overcomes any possible concurrency / volatility issues regarding the memory of what is being passed.

It's a case of "don't try to optimise here".

Returning by const is style. I usually don't, others prefer to just in case someone is gonig to do something with the returned value. Next you'll find people returning them by r-value reference...

I would normally go for your first option. The other alternative is pass by value (not necessary to use const) and return by const value.

Comment: "Next you'll find people returning them by r-value reference" - which would provoke UB, since you can't return an rvalue reference to a local object any more than you can return a plain reference to a local object. Hopefully those people can be cured fairly quickly.

Comment: Did the question change? All the parameters are 'by value'.